# Example of ASP.NET/C# using Facebook Connect Toolkit 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

Are there any examples of fully functioning code with C# and Facebook Connect with version 3.0 of the toolkit?

**NOTE:** I am specifically interested in version 3.0 of the toolkit. There are plenty of 2.0 examples out there but the 3.0 toolkit deprecates many of the 2.0 objects which makes these examples useless. I am **ONLY** interested in examples with 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great example here [asp-net-c-facebook-connect-api-example](http://www.lordyz.co.uk/2010/08/20/asp-net-c-facebook-connect-api-example/)

Answer (score 1):

Found this one:

http://www.rjygraham.com/archive/2009/11/22/using-facebook-connect-with-aspnet-mvc-and-the-facebook-developer-toolkit-3.aspx

Don't know how good it is yet...

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately I think the author is mistaken with that code. Version 3 of the toolkit does not support the "Api" object. So the code presented in that article wouldn't run. The author clearly claims that it should work with v3 but the code is not much different that then other v2 examples already out there.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, I think v3 supports Api object. Check Facebook.Rest.Api !